# Resources for Css Framework/Template for Data Entry / Forms

Tags: css, user-interface

I am looking for resources that provide good looking css templates / frameworks for data entry / forms. Interested in web "2.0" look e.g.

https://postmarkapp.com/sign_up

http://www.mailchimp.com/signup/

https://www.skyledger.com/public/plans/signup/free

Hoping we can get some good replies and make this a good resource for others.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: if you are after their css, why don't you just have a look in the source code? Then, if something doesn't work for you, you post it here and we'll help you out. You cannot expect us all to drop our whole code here and you'll pick whichever looks best to you, because all are good for their purpose. With no question asked, no answer will be correct.

Comment: @Bazzz - apparently you've never heard of sites with templates. Not expecting you to put all the css, just links to resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using BluePrint Css, they have a pretty nice form template.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the Wufoo - Online Form Builder?

http://wufoo.com/

http://wufoo.com/faq/

http://wufoo.com/examples/